# UILabel dynamic sizing- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, dynamic-sizing

I have created a UIView, and inside of this view there is a label with a image above the label.
The view looks like this: (don't mind the other labels on the side):

[image]

For the label that says "title" I wanted to make it so the height of it would be the height of the text, this is the code I used:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

The problem is that because of the image above it, the text will always stay as just one line...
My plan was that the image will resize based on how tall the text is, keeping its 3:4 aspect ratio using a constraint. I'm not sure why this doesn't work , but I think it's because of the constraints on the two elements.

These are the current constraints on the views:

label:

[image]

imageView (the trailing constraint is not the issue):

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> My plan was that the image will resize

The image view has a fixed leading constraint, a fixed trailing constraint, a fixed top, and a fixed aspect ratio. Therefore it cannot resize. You have absolutely determined its size.

I had no difficulty doing what I *think* you describing, with no code at all (just autolayout — the label text size is changed through dynamic text):

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks. But can you show me or tell me how you would accomplish this?

Comment: Well, you have not specified sufficiently what you want to do. You have fixed the image view, as I said, to its top, sides, and aspect ratio. The image view cannot change size. For the image view to change size, something would have to "give". But you have not said _what_ should give: you've just vaguely waved your hands and said that the image view should "resize". Experimentally, I would suggest you try deleting the trailing constraint and just see what happens.

Comment: Yeah you're right. for my solution I just added a constraint to the label that makes the height equal the height of the text (programmatically).

Comment: That doesn't sound right. A label under autolayout automatically _is_ the size of its height.

Comment: Yeah, its automatically the size of it's height but I think that the imageView caused the label to compress.

Comment: Well you need to tell it not to do that. If they have the same vertical compression resistance priority, the autolayout engine doesn't know which one to shrink.

Comment: Added a screenshot showing that it's simple to do what I _think_ you are trying to do (not sure).